# How to wirte a loop to repeat entire block code in r scripts?

Tags: r, loops

I want to import 15 different datasets and clean them up. Raw dataset names are like C1_1, C2_1, C3_1 ... C15_1.

My code is as follows for the first dataset:

```
dataC1_1 <- read.delim("C1_1.txt",header = FALSE)
dataC1_1 <- dataC1_1[-1,-c(1,4,8:11)]
dataC1_1 <- na.omit(dataC1_1)
dataC1_1 <- dataC1_1[!(dataC1_1$V3=="Experiment"),]
dataC1_1 <- dataC1_1[!(dataC1_1$V5=="Key: Return"),]
dataC1_1 <- dataC1_1[order(dataC1_1$V6),]
dataC1_1$q_id <- strrep(c("q1","q2","q3","q4"),times = 1)
dataC1_1$response <- dataC1_1$V5 %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
dataC1_1 <- dataC1_1[,-c(1,3,4)]
dataC1_1 <- setnames(dataC1_1,c("ad_id","rt","q_id","response"))
dataC1_1$id <-  rep("C1",length(dataC1_1$q_id))
```

I have tried so many times with while loop and if loop, but I just could not repeat 15 times.

Anyone could help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to apply on each of the datasets while reading the datasets in a loop

```
library(readr)
librar(dplyr)
library(stringr)
map2(sprintf("C%d_1", 1:15), str_c("C", 1:5), f1)
```

where

```
f1 <- function(nm, id) {
           read_csv(nm) %>%
            select(-c(1, 4, 8:11)) %>%
            slice(-1) %>%
            na.omit %>%
            filter(V3 != "Experiment"| V5 != "Key: Return") %>%
            arrange(V6) %>%
            mutate(q_id =  strrep(c("q1","q2","q3","q4"),times = 1),
                   response = str_match(V5,("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric)  %>%
            select(-c(1, 3, 4)) %>%
            set_names(c("ad_id","rt","q_id","response")) %>%
            mutate(id = id)
   }
```